# Storing an array of predetermined conditions

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I'm trying to create a static utility method that takes a single input of class `A`, instances of which have been given their own unique `id`, and retrieve a `boolean` value describing whether or not a certain characteristic applies to them. There is no pattern to describe the relationship; without a formula the two options that sprang first to mind were a `static final int[]` containing all of the true `id`s, or a string of "or" `||` tests. Are there other better options out there, or any particular advantage for using one over the other? The task is no large feat, but I'd like to be able to have it simple and readable.

Here's a sample to help you get a general idea of what I mean:

```
public class UtilitiesA {

    // first method of retrieval- static storage array
    private static int[] validIds = {
        A.instanceM.id, A.instanceZ.id, A.instanceL.id, A.instanceF.id, A.instanceP.id
    };

    public static boolean getHasCharacteristic(A input) {
        for (int id : validIds) if (a.id == id) return true;
        return false;
    }
    // vs the second method...
    public static boolean getHasCharacteristic2(A input) {
        return (input.id == A.instanceM.id ||
                input.id == A.instanceZ.id ||
                input.id == A.instanceL.id ||
                input.id == A.instanceF.id ||
                input.id == A.instanceP.id)
    }
}
```

The second is more intuitive I think, but also more repetitive. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
private static Integer[] validIds = {
    A.instanceM.id, A.instanceZ.id, A.instanceL.id, A.instanceF.id, A.instanceP.id
};

public static boolean getHasCharacteristic3(A input) {
       return Arrays.asList(validIds).contains(input.id)
   }
```

if you are going to be calling this often, you could just store all of the ids in an List in the first place instead of an array so that you don't have to convert the array into a List to use the contains method of List.

Note that if you keep it in an array, it must be an array of Integers and not ints.

Comment: Yes, it is going to be run roughly 0-10 times per cycle at 20Hz, so somewhat often. I might end up storing the data as a list, then.

Comment: Your first option is equally valid and I don't know that this will run any better or worse except that you can call it with a single line.

Comment: I do like how succinct it is.. might try to find out what List.contains is calling "under the hood".

Answer (score 0):

The second one even though it looks simple, will be inconvenient to code if the contents in your validIds are more. In that for every value inside that array you will have to check. If the number of contents are more, it is possible that you might end up missing one or other values. So It is recommended that you should iterate using the for loop as u have done in the first implementation